# Loading pretrained model in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection-api

In this [tutorial](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/defining_your_own_model.md) (creating new model for object detection), it is mentioned at the middle as

"We typically initialize the weights of this feature extractor using those from the Slim Resnet-101 classification checkpoint, and we know that images were preprocessed when training this checkpoint by subtracting a channel mean from each input image. Thus, we implement the preprocess function to replicate the same channel mean subtraction behavior."

Now I am trying to load pretrained model for `MobileNet_v1_1.0_224` at this [page](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/defining_your_own_model.md).

I checked all variables from loaded checkpoint and those variables required to initialize in training FasterRcnn. Loaded checkpoint has more varaibles than those needed.

For example,
I need to initialize this variable `'FirstStageFeatureExtractor/MobilenetV1/Conv2d_0/BatchNorm/beta'`.

But in loaded variables have

```
'MobilenetV1/Conv2d_0/BatchNorm/beta/ExponentialMovingAverage': [32]
'MobilenetV1/Conv2d_0/BatchNorm/beta/RMSProp_1': [32],
'MobilenetV1/Conv2d_0/BatchNorm/beta': [32],
```

My queries are

(1)So for me, it is enough to use the last one `'MobilenetV1/Conv2d_0/BatchNorm/beta'` to initialize to `'FirstStageFeatureExtractor/MobilenetV1/Conv2d_0/BatchNorm/beta'`.

Is it correct?

(2)What ExponentialMovingAverage and RMSProp_1 are for?

(3)Then how FirstStageFeatureExtractor and SecondStageFeatureExtractor are separated in FasterRcnn in Tensorflow?

(4)Those variables initialized use initialized weights, for those variable not initialized will use  `Xavier initializer` according to config file, is it true?

```
initializer {
    variance_scaling_initializer {
        factor: 1.0
        uniform: true
        mode: FAN_AVG
    }
}
```

EDIT:

Then for the variable `MobilenetV1/Conv2d_12_pointwise/depthwise_weights shape=(3, 3, 512, 1)`, I can't find exact variable.
Those closer are

```
'MobilenetV1/Conv2d_12_depthwise/depthwise_weights': [3, 3, 512, 1],
'MobilenetV1/Conv2d_12_depthwise/depthwise_weights/RMSProp': [3, 3, 512, 1],
'MobilenetV1/Conv2d_12_depthwise/depthwise_weights/ExponentialMovingAverage': [3, 3, 512, 1],
'MobilenetV1/Conv2d_12_depthwise/depthwise_weights/RMSProp_1': [3, 3, 512, 1],
```

So I used weights of variable 'MobilenetV1/Conv2d_12_depthwise/depthwise_weights': [3, 3, 512, 1], from loaded checkpoint to assign to 
`MobilenetV1/Conv2d_12_pointwise/depthwise_weights shape=(3, 3, 512, 1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes what I did was correct. What variables are needed to initialize and what variable are available from loaded checkpoint can be checked from `variable_names_map`. From there, select the variable and initialize to further fine tuning.

Need a bit of modification to the Tensorflow's code mainly at `utils/variables_helper.py file.`

What to be in FirstStage and SecondStage of FasterRCNN are decided at `faster_rcnn_mobilenet_v1_feature_extractor.py`